# Как открыть файл/приложение через язык c++

Tags: c++

Код не открывает приложение, в чем ошибка

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>



int main() {
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    system("Start C:\\Program Files(x86)\\Steam\\steam.exe");

    for(;;) {}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Путь с пробелами следует обрамлять кавычками. `Start` не нужен, как и `SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); SetConsoleCP(1251);`

Comment: Гуглить `ShellExecute()`. Не кросс-платформенная, в отличие от `std::system`, но не открывает некрасивое окно консоли.

Comment: @user7860670 можешь подправить строку с system? не могу понять как сделать.

Comment: попробуйте как [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290099/c-system-function) сделать. как я понял, требуются дополнительные кавычки, либо убрать start

Answer (score 0):

Ф-ция **system** отдает на выполнение команду, переданную в единственном параметре, командному интерпретатору **cmd.exe** (Windows), в Linux-е скорее всего это будет **bash**. Соответственно для запуска процесса необходимо передавать, такую команду, как если бы она была передана командному интерпретатору напрямую, т.е. вот так "C:\Program Files(x86)\Steam\steam.exe".

В коде это будет вот так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    system("\"C:\\Program Files(x86)\\Steam\\steam.exe\"");

    for(;;) {}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку: "C:\Program" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: Путь до программы необходимо взять в двойные кавычки, т.е. запустить **cmd.exe** и выполнить команду: **"C:\Program Files(x86)\Steam\steam.exe"**